# TensorFlow Segmentation Fault

Tags: python, tensorflow

So I'm running a GAN on TensorFlow and as soon as the first epoch is about to finish I get a segmentation fault that looks like  `zsh:/Users/****/miniforge3/envs/python386/bin/python`

How would I fix this?

CODE:
[Code](https://pastebin.com/yrP2aXHK)

EDIT: For anyone who comes across this question. For some reason threaded processes don't fully function on a mac m1.

Comment: What's the code? (it might be needed to see why)

Comment: Can't see it yet

Comment: @Someone_who_likes_SE Can you see it now?